# Web Test Runner Visual Regression Test passes when a test file is executed separately but fails if its executed recursively

Tags: npm

I'm using @web/test-runner-visual-regression for testing web components along with Web Test Runner. My test file is pretty simple.

```
import { html, fixture, expect } from '@open-wc/testing';
import { visualDiff } from '@web/test-runner-visual-regression';

describe('Clickable Card Spec', function() { 
it("component passes visual regression", async () => {
      const el: Card = await fixture(html` <my-element icon="upload" label="Test" cid="card_1"> </my-element> `);
      await visualDiff(el, "uwc-card");
    });
}
```

This test case passes when this file is executed separately. I also have a couple of test files and when all are run recursively the above test case fails with the following error:

```
Error: Node is detached from document
    at CDPElementHandle.assertConnectedElement (C:\BBRepos\dsf-uux_3\node_modules\puppeteer-core\lib\cjs\puppeteer\api\ElementHandle.js:590:19)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async CDPElementHandle.scrollIntoView (C:\BBRepos\dsf-uux_3\node_modules\puppeteer-core\lib\cjs\puppeteer\common\ElementHandle.js:107:9)
    at async CDPElementHandle.scrollIntoViewIfNeeded (C:\BBRepos\dsf-uux_3\node_modules\puppeteer-core\lib\cjs\puppeteer\api\ElementHandle.js:602:9)
    at async CDPElementHandle.screenshot (C:\BBRepos\dsf-uux_3\node_modules\puppeteer-core\lib\cjs\puppeteer\common\ElementHandle.js:406:9)
    at async Object.executeCommand (C:\BBRepos\dsf-uux_3\node_modules\@web\test-runner-visual-regression\dist\visualRegressionPlugin.js:45:45)
    at async TestRunnerApiPlugin._onCommand (C:\BBRepos\dsf-uux_3\node_modules\@web\test-runner-core\dist\server\plugins\api\testRunnerApiPlugin.js:145:32)

Error: Error while executing command visual-diff with payload {"id":"1","name":"my-element"}: Did not receive a server response for message with type wtr-command within 20000ms
```

Any help is highly appreciated!

I tried by increasing the timeout using "this.timeout(xx)" but nothing worked!